# django x++ in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

this is my code:

```
{% for d in do %}
{% x=0 %}
 <tr class="{{ class.x }}">
{% x++ %}
  <td>{{ d.year }}/{{ d.month }}/{{ d.day }}</td>
  <td>{{ d.customer }}</td>
  <td>{{ d.cost }} تومان</td>
  <td>{{ d.forwhat }}</td>
  <td>{{ d.description }}</td>
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

how I can do `x++` in template?
I get do from database and sort by year , month and day.
Now i want for each d in do add `1` to `x` and call `class.x` data from

```
class: ['red', 'yellow', 'green', ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cycle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle):

```
<table>
{% for x in z %}
 <tr class="{% cycle "red" "blue" "green" %}">
  <td>{{ x }}</td>
 </tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>
<style>
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

Result:

[image]

Although I'm not sure if this the most elegant way to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You have to put `x` outside of the loop.

```
{% with x=0 %}
{% for d in do %}
<tr class="{{ class.x }}">
{% x++ %}
  <td>{{ d.year }}/{{ d.month }}/{{ d.day }}</td>
  <td>{{ d.customer }}</td>
  <td>{{ d.cost }} تومان</td>
  <td>{{ d.forwhat }}</td>
  <td>{{ d.description }}</td>
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

or you can use `{{ forloop.counter }}` inside the loop.

Comment: show: Invalid block tag on line 96: 'x=0'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
for {% x=0 %}

Comment: {% for d in do %}
            {% with forloop.counter-1 as x %}
          <tr class="{{ class.x }}">
            {% endwith %}

Comment: Could not parse the remainder: '-1' from 'forloop.counter-1

Comment: without '-1' dont do any thing

Comment: have you tried without forloop counter it should work.

Comment: `{% with x=0 %}
{% for d in do %}
<tr class="{{ class.x }}">
{% x++ %}
  <td>{{ d.year }}/{{ d.month }}/{{ d.day }}</td>
  <td>{{ d.customer }}</td>
  <td>{{ d.cost }} تومان</td>
  <td>{{ d.forwhat }}</td>
  <td>{{ d.description }}</td>
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}`

Comment: Invalid block tag on line 99: 'x++', expected 'endwith'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: show me the full error code .. update the question please. because the `endswith` is there in the code.